# DKIM record value format

Tags: dkim

I've created public and private keys in cPanel > Email > Encryption for mydomain.com and now want to use the public key in the DNS control panel, which is in GoDaddy's shared hosting account control panel. GoDaddy support say they are not allowed to advise on DKIM records because they are not trained on DNS, however some seem to have suceeded with [DKIM records on GoDaddy](https://community.godaddy.com/s/question/0D53t00006VmZWNCA3/dkim-txt-setup-in-domain-manager).

In the domain DNS, when adding a new record, I've selected 'TXT' for Type and entered 'default._domainkey' for Name. Then if I start the value field with 'v=DKIM1;' do I need to base64 encode the public key before adding it after 'p='?

If I add the public key after base64 encoding the string becomes too long. The solution mentioned on the web is to encapsulate the string in double quotes and split the key with 2x double quotes with space in between, but that doesn't seem to be recognised when the record is saved.

Anyone else had more luck?

Comment: As the dns tag explains: DNS QUESTIONS MUST BE PROGRAMMING RELATED. Use this tag for programming questions related to writing code that interacts with the Domain Name System (DNS); for example, writing code that uses gethostbyname()

Comment: You'd have better luck posting this question on ServerFault.com forum.

Comment: @Reinto thank you for the prompt, I've created a question at https://serverfault.com/questions/1131343/dkim-on-godaddy-shared-hosting